Forest Multiple Labels
I am trying to draw forests. I am able to add a single label to edges, but I do not know how to add a second one.
Here is the code I have:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathreplacing}



\begin{document}



\begin{figure} 
\centering
\begin{forest}
for tree={
    coordinate, calign=fixed edge angles, calign angle=25, edge=thick,
    {}
}
[
    [,l*=2,edge label={node[midway,right]{$l_{1}$}}]
    [
        [,l*=2,edge label={node[end, below]{$l_{2}$},node[end, below]{0}},edge label={node[midway,left]{0}}]
        [,edge label={node[end, below]{$l_{3}$}},edge label={node[midway,right]{1}}]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
    coordinate, calign=fixed edge angles, calign angle=25, edge=thick,{}}
[
    [,no edge]
    [,no edge]
]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
    coordinate, calign=fixed edge angles, calign angle=25, edge=thick,
    {}
}
[
    [,l*=2,edge label={node[end, below]{$l_{3}$}}]
    [
        [,l*=2,edge label={node[end, below]{$l_{1}$}}]
        [,edge label={node[end, below]{$l_{2}$}}]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{figure} 
\end{document}

Ideally I need to be able to create a tree that will have labels from the two trees simultaneously. My guess is that there is a simple command that I do not know. Thanks for all the help.

Your code gives an error: how is end defined?

I do not know what the error is or how to fix it. Latex is a new tool for me and I have not yet understood how to do complicated stuff with it. I still have a bunch of junk in my main code, but since at the end it all works I decided rather not to alter it.

If you run the code you posted, it returns an error. I can't remember now. There might have been more than one. The one I can remember, at least, is explained in my answer, as well as how to fix it. I then give an example of code which includes the correction. So I don't know what you don't know about that error or how to fix it. Nor do I know what more I might say about it beyond what's in my answer already.

I take it end should be at end as the former gives an error. If not, obviously you can change it back once it is defined.
You can add as many nodes as you wish into a single edge label.
      [,l*=2,edge label={node[at end, below]{$l_{2}$}node[at end, right]{0}node[midway,left]{0}node [at end,left]{$l_2$}}]

Alternatively, you can invoke the option multiple times using edge label+ to avoid overwriting earlier uses.
    [,l*=2,edge label={node[midway,right]{$l_{1}$}},edge label+={node[at end,below]{$l_3$}}]

Complete code:
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    coordinate, calign=fixed edge angles, calign angle=25, edge=thick,
    {}
  }
  [
    [,l*=2,edge label={node[midway,right]{$l_{1}$}},edge label+={node[at end,below]{$l_3$}}]
    [
      [,l*=2,edge label={node[at end, below]{$l_{2}$}node[at end, right]{0}node[midway,left]{0}node [at end,left]{$l_2$}}]
      [,edge label={node[at end, below]{$l_{3}$}node[midway,right]{1}node[at end,left]{$l_2$}}]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}

Apologies for the lack of an image. Currently Okular-on-X has a bug and I've not yet found a workaround.
